# Что внутри конструктора по умолчанию?

Tags: java, ооп, конструктор

Допустим если мы объявим конструктор, то он будет возвращать нам некоторую информацию, и мы будем знать какую, а если этого не делать?

Comment: Конструктор по-умолчанию возвращает объект с полями, значения которых будут заданы по-умолчанию.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понял Ваш вопрос, то он заключается в том, какие значения будут иметь поля, если в конструкторе не будет их инициализации. Если так, то ответ простой:
- все поля, имеющие примитивные типы, получат значения по умолчанию
- все поля, имеющие объектные типы, получат null
Пример:

```
public class A {
    private int i;
    private long y;
    private boolean b;
    private String str;

    public A() {}
}
```

В этом случае i и y будут иметь значение 0, b = false, а str = null (строки в Java являются объектами).

Совсем другое дело, если поля отмечены ключевым словом final. Это означает что они обязаны быть проинициализированы либо в месте объявления, либо в конструкторе. Без их инициализации код не скомпилируется.